# Error messages while starting Cassandra node

Tags: cassandra, nosql

**UPDATE: Seems to be some corrupt SSTable files. I have since deleted them and the instances of these messages are far less to none now. Thanks for all your help!**

About everytime I start a Cassandra node, this appears in the logs for several times before it is up and running...

```
Fatal exception in thread Thread[SSTableBatchOpen:2,5,main] java.lang.AssertionError
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.open(SSTableReader.java:150)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader$1.run(SSTableReader.java:224)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can someone advise me on the best course of action to prevent this from future occurences?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you running?  That would help with making sense of the line numbers in your stacktrace.  Thx!

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am using the latest Cassandra 1.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some problem opening with SSTable, for read. 
Can you run in DEBUG mode  https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/conf/log4j-server.properties#L21

Comment: Thanks Samal. I shall try that out and follow up.

Comment: Hi Samal,

I have enabled the debug mode and think I shall try deleting those files that it tried to open just before these error messages occurred.

Thanks again!  :)