# apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException -- Cassandra times out seemingly because of garbage?

Tags: timeout, cassandra

I use a Cassandra node (one node) on a development system and a while back when running "strong tests" (as in very fast write tests) I got many errors. These we see questions about them all over the place and no real answers about them only that you just cannot go too fast. Okay, I'm generally fine with that.

However, today I was using the system as I would in production and get a table that would generate the time out error. This is in READ mode (the partial write in the error is on the socket, not to the database).

```
Thrift: Tue Feb  4 01:46:44 2014 TSocket::write_partial() send() <Host: 127.0.0.1 Port: 9160>Broken pipe
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'apache::thrift::transport::TTransportException'
  what():  write() send(): Broken pipe
```

The big problem, in this case, is that I just could not access a row in one of my tables. Trying to access that row would always timeout.  I restarted the node, waited some time, no change. The row was just hosed.

Anyone ran in such problems before? If so, did you have a way to fix it? That specific row I could have regenerated it, but what would happen in a cluster with many nodes? Could a row on one node decide to break the entire system? (that one row was breaking my development system!) If you have ideas, I'd like to hear about them so next time it happens I can look into a fix instead of blowing up the whole database and create a new one (I could just delete the tables and restart fresh, no need to delete the whole cluster, but still... but that's not a solution in a production system.)

======== UPDATE

Ah! Nevermind, I was looking at the wrong log file (development systems, I'll tell you...). The error is an EOFException.

```
ERROR [ReadStage:29174] 2014-02-04 01:17:00,587 CassandraDaemon.java (line 185) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:29174,5,main]
java.io.IOError: java.io.EOFException
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:79)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:64)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:88)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SimpleSliceReader.computeNext(SimpleSliceReader.java:37)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableSliceIterator.hasNext(SSTableSliceIterator.java:82)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.getNext(QueryFilter.java:157)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter$2.hasNext(QueryFilter.java:140)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$OneToOne.computeNext(MergeIterator.java:200)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.collectReducedColumns(SliceQueryFilter.java:189)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateColumns(QueryFilter.java:122)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:80)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:72)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:294)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:53)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1468)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1294)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.getRow(Keyspace.java:332)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:65)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1365)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1897)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:416)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:394)
at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.RandomAccessReader.readBytes(RandomAccessReader.java:348)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.read(ByteBufferUtil.java:392)
at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readWithLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:355)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnSerializer.deserializeColumnBody(ColumnSerializer.java:118)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.OnDiskAtom$Serializer.deserializeFromSSTable(OnDiskAtom.java:85)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column$1.computeNext(Column.java:75)
... 28 more
```

Comment: Does Cassandra log an error, too? Or just the client? Timeouts normally appear as that in the logs.

Comment: No I could not see anything in the logs. I would imagine that errors would show up in there... I'll make sure to increase the log level just in case it happens again so I get more info next time.

Comment: I guess I commented too fast! Looking at the log setup, it is on INFO so I'd already get quite a bit of logs. The fact is I was looking at an old log. I can now see the error as updated in the question.

Comment: Does this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898085/cassandra-eofexception-thrown-on-some-queries-after-a-power-failure) help?

Comment: Ah! That's good news to read that by deleting the sstable you'd fix the problem with auto-replication. That said, it means we have better have 3+ nodes to make sure. One node environments would probably be precluded from a production system... This being said, I'll have to test the next time I get such an error to be sure it works!

Answer (score 0):

Ralf pointed me to a page where Richard had an answer saying:

> « you can just delete the corrupt SSTable then run repair to recover the data from the replicas. »

So I tried today since I got that same kind of error again and it actually worked. That is, since I have a single node, the repair is actually useless from what I can tell. However, the "delete corrupt SSTable" part works nicely. As soon as I did a scrub for a given table, I could read the row that was generating a timeout (i.e. the timeout happens because Cassandra throws and thus never replies to thrift which after a little while decides to throw a timeout error on the client side.)

In my case, I ran the following command and got the problem resolved for the table named `files`:

```
nodetool scrub snap_websites files
               ^             ^
               |             |
               |             +--- your table name
               +--- your context name
```